# Magento delete product compare

Tags: magento

I use magento and I have my own template but on my product detail page on the left side I have compare products. How can I delete this block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create local.xml file under your theme/layout/local.xml and place below code.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <!-- remove compare products -->
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

This block is added in layout files. You can remove this block in original files or in your extension layout.

By default this block is added in files

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml
/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
```

1) Copy this files to your theme folder and remove strings

```
<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
```

2) In your layout file add lines

```
<default>
    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>

<customer_account>
    <reference name="left">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

Answer (score 0):

To completely disable compare products functionality you can use this [free extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/16044/).

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the file /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/compare/sidebar.html or rename it.

Answer (score -2):

Just remove this block from `layout/catalog.xml` and `compare products section` will be gone :

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" after="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: It won't remove from product page.